# Different between Microsoft.AspNet.OData And System.Web.Http.OData

Tags: asp.net, api, odata

Which is better to use for Api?

using System.Web.Http.OData.Builder;
using System.Web.Http.OData.Extensions;

using Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Extensions;

Answer (score 2):

The different namespaces represent different versions of either the OData protocol, or the implementations thereof.

```
+------------------------+---------------+-----------------+
| Namespace              | OData Version | Library Version |
+------------------------+---------------+-----------------+
| System.Web.Http.OData  | v3            | 6               |
| System.Web.OData       | v4            | 6               |
| Microsoft.AspNet.OData | v4            | 7               |
+------------------------+---------------+-----------------+
```

I'd recommend going with the latest stuff as it gets the best support, so that would be [Microsoft.AspNet.OData](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.OData/)